GitHub doesn't list latest release as "latest"
I've set of organizational private repos with quite long lists of releases. Releases have names N-Y.M.D-X where N is sequential number, Y.M.D is date of the release and X could be commit hashcode or combination of branch name and hashcode.

The problem is the release 9-2024.10.13-607d6fd (from two weeks ago) is still marked as "latest" even if there are other recent releases (the actual last one - 17-2024.10.15-rename-models-1533982 - is from last week).
It looks like GitHub changed the way of latest evaluation from different day timestamps or consider the version number (9-2024 > 17-2024 lexicographically) prior the release timestamp.
Is there a way to fix that? Is it a problem of GitHub or the format of the first part of version number N-Y?
BTW: If list releases by tag then they are ordered right way.

You can mark a release as latest. If you go into the editing mode for a release, at the bottom there is a checkbox to mark it as latest.

We use ncipollo/release-action@v1 GitHub action to make releases. I don't why it was working well before, but anyway I found I can pass makeLatest: true for the release and it will be marked as latest. It resolved the problem.

Unless you tell it otherwise, Github does not pick the latest release by date, it picks it by semantic versioning. From Creating A Release...

Optionally, select Set as latest release. If you do not select this option, the latest release label will automatically be assigned based on semantic versioning.

You're not using semantic versioning, so it's anyone's guess what Github will do. Best to mark it explicitly.

Is it a problem of GitHub or the format of the first part of version number N-Y?

Rather than guess at what every projects unique version numbering scheme means, Github (and many others) have adopted semantic versioning. This provides a clear meaning and grammar and sort order for versions.
N-Y.M.D-X is not a valid semver as each point must be a positive integer. You can adapt your format to be a semantic version using build metadata. I'd suggest something like 1.2.3+20241025.rename-models.deadb33f

Good point! Unfortunately, I don't have option to change versioning, so explicit mark of latest seems the only case (and it works). Thank you.
